# Using a generating function to solve combinatorics problems with ice cream sundaes

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I just started learning about generating functions and was trying to solve a problem on my own. If anyone can give me feedback on my solution. Letting me know if it is right or wrong or any place I made a mistake it will be greatly appreciated! Thank you! [image]

According to the textbook the solution is C(12+5-1,12)-5 X C(7+5-1,7)+C(5,2)X C(2+5-1,2) but when I evaluate that and compare it to my solution I get a different number.

Comment: You are missing some terms: The expansion for $$(1-x)^{-5}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{k+4}{4}x^k$$ is infinite so it contributes to the $x^{12}$ coefficient *for each* of the 3 terms $1$, $-\binom{5}{1}x^5$ and $\binom{5}{2}x^{10}$ multiplying it.

Comment: do I need consider the fact that in order to get the coefficient of x^12 I can take either all of the xs from h(x) and none from f(x), 5 from f(x) and 7 from h(x), or 10 from f (x) and 2 from h(x). Then sum all the cases?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Assuming $h(x)=(1-x)^{-5}$ and $f(x)=(1-x^5)^5$.

Comment: alright makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you still want some explanation on expanding negative binomials? As per you comment on the answer. Please do read the Mathjax tutorial btw as suggested by @awkward.

Comment: @N.Shales Available in chat for a combinatorics question?

Comment: I am now. Let me know when.

Comment: @N.Shales me too. Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't you have to open a room or something and invite me? Never done it myself.

Comment: you were in my room before actually

Answer (score 1):

Please post your questions in MathJax instead of posting a picture.  Images can't be located by searches.  There is a tutorial on MathJax here: [MathJax Tutorial and Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Hint: Note that
$$\frac{(1-x^5)^5}{(1-x)^5}=(1-x^5)^5 \cdot (1-x)^{-5}$$
and then use the Binomial Theorem for a negative power to expand 
$$(1-x)^{-5} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{5+i-1}{i} x^i$$

Your mistake is in expanding $(1-x)^5$ instead of $(1-x)^{-5}$.

Comment: any chance someone can show me expanding the negative power in more detail. I'm still a little confused. Thank you!

Comment: do I need consider the fact that in order to get the coefficient of x^12 I can take either all of the xs from h(x) and none from f(x), 5 from f(x) and 7 from h(x), or 10 from f (x) and 2 from h(x). Then sum all the cases?

Comment: Expand both $(1-x^5)^5$ and $(1-x)^{-5}$.  You then have the product of two series, say one in $x^j$ and one in $x^i$.  You want to sum the cases where $i+j=12$.